# How to set is_staff to True in Django when a user is created with a specific group selected

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

How would I automatically set is_staff to True when creating a new user in the Django admin when they have a specific group selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve it using the django signal.

Just listen when a user created or updated its group. when it is created or updated with the specific group selected, You just set is_staff=True and save it.

To learn more about Django signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/

Learn more about Django group and permission https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups

Comment: This worked perfectly once I figured out that I needed to listen for an m2m_change and not just the creation of a user.  Thank you!